# Convert epoch timestamp to date time format using camus properties

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, camus

My kafka message has multiple fields which contain epoch timestamps in long format. My message looks like this :

```
{
    "someDate1":1512725505000,
    "someDate2":1518060461000,
    "ABC":"XYZ",
    "PQR":"MNO"
}
```

Is there a way to convert all these epoch timestamps to date time format when loading into hdfs using some property in the camus properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Camus is depreciated - you're better off using the [HDFS connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html#quickstart) for Kafka Connect. It is open source and available [standalone](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/) or as part of [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/).

As part of Kafka Connect you have [Single Message Transforms](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_transforms), which you can use to convert your epochs to a more readable form - see `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter`

See more an example of Single Message Transform in action in this [blog article here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/).